# Finite-dimensional irreducible representations of 2-loop quiver

Tags: rt.representation-theory, modules, quivers

What are the finite-dimensional irreducible representations of the quiver with one vertex and two loops?

Comment: Isn't this the same as classifying pairs of matrices up to simultaneous conjugation? This is a well-known "wild" classification problem (in fact, it is the prototype/definition of "wild") so it is generally thought to be hopeless...

Comment: @SamHopkins they said irreducible representations.  The module category can be wild and irreducible representations not wild.  For example any finite acyclic quiver that is not Dynkin has wild representation type but finitely many irreducibles and are easy to describe but the indecomposables are wild.  This question still seems hard though since you are clarifying up to simultaneous conjugacy pairs of matrices that generate the whole matrix algebra

Comment: L. Le Bruyn, C. Procesi, Semisimple representations  of quivers, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 317(1990) 585–598, Theorem 4 should be relevant.

Comment: Sometimes the difference in reception of a question between MathSE and MO can be surreal. [This question was deleted on MathSE for missing context](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4183721/167197)